# Is it correct to use gerund in these sentences?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-clauses

1. "A woman **speaking** to the TV channel said that it seems nearly impossible to find a retirement home."

My question is if it is the same as "a woman who **is/was speaking** to ...."

2. Same question here: "They only admit patients **requiring** urgent care" = "They only admit patients **that is requiring** urgent care." ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a reduced-relative clause?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217498/is-this-a-reduced-relative-clause) [Reduced relative clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114163/reduced-relative-clauses)

Comment: [grammar correction: Is it correct to use **a** gerund in these sentences?] said that it seem**ed**

Comment: patients **who require** urgent care.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of meaning, it is the same. In terms of grammatical construction, it is not the same.

> A woman **speaking to the TV channel**...

The part marked in bold is a participial phrase that acts like a defining adjective on woman.

> A woman **who was speaking to the TV channel**...

This is a relative clause where the relative pronoun **who** links the relative clause to the noun that it follows (woman).

Some people would describe the participial phrase version as an example of whiz-deletion.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *A woman* [*who was speaking to the TV channel*] *said that it seems nearly*
>   *impossible to find a retirement home*.
>
> [2] *A woman* [*speaking to the TV channel*] *said that it seems nearly*
>   *impossible to find a retirement home.*

Yes, [2] is an alternant to [1], and they both have similar meanings.

But there is a slight grammatical difference: although the bracketed element in both cases is modifying "woman", in [1] it's a relative clause, while in [2] it's a gerund-participial one.

You will likely encounter the term 'reduced relative clause' (or *'whizz*-deletion') used to describe the one in [2], but it's a misnomer, since there is no possibility of the clause containing a relative phrase: we can't say *"a woman who speaking to the TV channels.